# The cutoff for eating חדש was delayed after the בית המקדש; what about the cutoff for its taking root?

Tags: derabanan, churban-destruction, deorayta, yashan-chadash

We used to bring a flour-offering called the "*omer*" on the sixteenth of *Nisan*. The *halacha*, as practiced when we had a *bes hamikdash*, is that any grain that took root after the *omer* is brought one year cannot be eaten until after the *omer* is brought the following year.

After the *bes hamikdash* was destroyed, however, such grain became permitted as of the morning of the sixteenth. That's by divine deceee; *Raban Yochanan ben Zakay*, however, decreed that it become permitted as of the start (night) of the seventeenth, so that, when the *bes hamikdash* is rebuilt, no one err and eat such grain in the morning of the sixteenth, before it becomes permitted with the *omer*'s being brought.

All the above is from the *Mishna* and *Bavli*, *M'nachos* 68, and the *Mishna* on 70. When the grain had to have taken root is actually disputed in the *Bavli* there: some say it had to have taken root before the *omer* grain was cut from the ground, on the night of the sixteenth; others, before the *omer* offering was brought. (*Mishne Tora*, *Maachalos Asuros* 10:4, rules according to the latter view.)

Until the *bes hamikdash* was destroyed, the prohibition applied to any grain that took root before the *omer*. What about nowadays?

1. In the absence of a *bes hamikdash*, what's the divinely-decreed cutoff time for grain's taking root so it is permitted by this year's seventeenth of *Nisan*?
2. If that cutoff is **after** the time the *omer* was cut from the ground (or, according to the way we rule, after the time the *omer* was brought), did *Raban Yochanan ben Zakay* make a decree pushing the cutoff earlier, for the same reason as his other decree?
3. If not, why not? Alternatively, if he did, why isn't it mentioned in the *Mishna* like his other decree?

Comment: If the answer to 2 is "no", then I suspect the answer to 3 may be "one doesn't make a decree about rare cases, and no one plants wheat at that time of year". But my knowledge of agriculture is weak enough that I'm not sure that makes sense; and, anyway, if it _does_ make sense, I'd still like to see a source for it.

Comment: Kitzur SA 172: תְבוּאָה שֶׁנִּזְרְעָה וְנִשְׁרְשָׁה קֹדֶם ט"ז בְּנִיסָן, הַעֹמֶר הַזֶה הִתִּירָהּ, וּמֻתֶּרֶת מִיָד לְאַחַר קְצִירָתָהּ. אֲבָל אִם לֹא נִשְׁרְשָׁה קֹדֶם שִׁשָׁה עָשָׂר בְּנִיסָן, אֲסוּרָה עַד שֶׁיָבוֹא הָעֹמֶר הַבָּא - but that leaves your other questions.